# Cannot modify any setting on S3 bucket from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS.
When I added the bucket policy in the link. I lost all control from AWS console. What should I do change policy from console again.

[Restricting Access to a Specific VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html#example-bucket-policies-restrict-access-vpc)

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909153",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common problem, please refer to this link : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152006

Comment: Thank you Alex. I read the forum topic and I just see what I already tried.

Comment: @HashimOtto are you sure?  Deleting the bucket policy using the root account is the correct solution, and is mentioned at that link.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not accurate. I did all what I can do. Now I'm requesting who has root account to remove all bucket policy. I need to wait his answer.